# In Hibernate mappings : how to set default value?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

> In my project i want to set default value of three columns i'm using this code in x.hbm.xml file:

```
<property name="occupation" type="string">
        <column name="occupation" length="20" not-null="false" default="Not Provided" />
    </property><property name="address" type="string">
        <column name="address" length="150" not-null="false" default="Not Provided"  />
    </property><property name="contact" type="string">
        <column name="contact" length="15" not-null="false" default="Not Provided" />
    </property>
```

> when all three values are not provided by user then only first(occupation) is set to default value others not.. or more then one field is not provided then only one column get default value other not..

Answer (score 1):

I tried it using annotations.

```
@Column(name = "colName", insertable=false, updatable = false, nullable = false, 
        columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default '14-APR-1981'")
```

or you can use `@PrePersist` annotation

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
if(myProperty == null) //We set default value in case if the value is not set yet.
    myProperty = "Default value";
}
```

Comment: i dont know about annotation in hibernate so please can u tell me excactly where i have to put this code ??

Comment: This is really old and you probably figured it out, but you put this in the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

That's not setting the default value that you asked, but set one field with string "Not Provided" if one or more field is null. Is that right?

the easiest way to understand is to modify your constructor and setter so you can filter it manually, something like this:

```
public class YourTable {
  private String occupation;
  private String address;
  private String contact;

  public YourTable (){
    checkNull();
  }

  //your geter setter here, and each setter must call checkNull() method after setting it's value

  private void checkNull(){
    if(occupation==null){
      occupation="Not Provided";
      return;
    }
    if(address==null){
      address="Not Provided";
      return;
    }
    if(contact==null){
      contact="Not Provided";
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside servlet i have added this code to check if any value is not provided by user then set it as Not Provided and then insert values.

```
            if (occupation.equals("")) {
                occupation = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (address.equals("")) {
                address = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (contact.equals("")) {
                contact = "Not Provided";
            }
```